# Char array issue in c

Tags: c, memory-management

Here is my code:

```
 #include        
 #include        

 int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

        const char **keywords;
        const char **values;
        char line[50];
        char *prop, *val, *tmp;
        int i = 0, j = 0;
        FILE *creds = fopen("/path/to/file.props", "r");

        keywords = malloc(5);
        values = malloc(5);

        while (fgets(line, LINE_SIZE, creds) != NULL) {
                if (line[strlen(line) - 1] == '\n')
                        line[strlen(line) - 1] = '\0';
                prop = line; 
                while(*(prop++) != '=') {
                        i++;
                }       
                tmp = prop;
                prop = malloc(i + 1);
                strncpy(prop, line, i);
                prop[i] = '\0';
                keywords[j] = prop;
                val = malloc(strlen(line) - strlen(prop));
                strcpy(val, tmp);
                values[j++] = val;
                i = 0;
        }
printf("%s %s %s %s %s\n", keywords[0], keywords[1], keywords[2], keywords[3], keywords[4]);
}
```

Now, the `file.props` has that content:

```
hostaddr=127.0.0.1
port=5432
user=username
password=mypass
dbname=my_db_name
```

And when I run the program I get:

> @raddr port user password dbname

If I comment the line with `values[j++] = val` and increment `j` properly, the output is how it should be:

> hostaddr port user password dbname
>   .

Can anybody guide me and show what's the problem with my code?

Comment: `keywords` and `values` are pointers to pointers. You need to set both levels of indirection before using the variables: `values = malloc(n * sizeof *values); for (k = 0; k < n; k++) values[k] = malloc(<whatever>);`. Don't forget to free the pointers in the reverse order.

Comment: @pmg Can you explain me why should I free them in reverse order? Thanks.

Comment: If you were to free the pointers starting with `values` instead of `values[k]`, after `free(values);` the statement `free(values[0]);` invokes Undefined Behaviour because `values` itself is no longer valid.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The lines

```
keywords = malloc(5);
values = malloc(5);
```

give you 5 bytes of memory.  I presume you want 5 element arrays instead.  These would be allocated like

```
keywords = malloc(5 * sizeof(*keywords));
values = malloc(5 * sizeof(*values));
```

At present, you're writing beyond the end of the memory allocated for `keywords`  and `values`.  The effects of this are undefined (so unpredictable) but it sounds like writing beyond the end of one array is corrupting memory used by the other array.

Comment: what if I don't know `*keywords` size? Should I put an approximation size (like 50 in my case)?

Comment: Deleted mine, since there's no point for having duplicates. +1

Comment: @artaxerxe `keywords` has type `const char**` so `*keywords` has type `const char*`.  The size of a pointer type will always be known at compile time.  You do however need to hard-code the number of elements you need.  My code hard-codes these to 5 (copied from your question).